# Combine Cardinality Aggregation with a 'where' condition?

Tags: elasticsearch, cardinality, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm trying to create a **distinct count hits based on a field** but I'm stuck.

How can I combine Cardinality and a condition like `"select distinct(lastname) from table where name like 'George%'"`?

How can I use 'where' condition with Cardinality?

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "test_count" : {
            "cardinality" : {
                "field" : "lastname"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Did you try something as below to get distinct counts of lastNames, with `firstName` like 'George'**

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:9200/gccount/Customer/_search?pretty=true" -d'                       
{                                                                                                   
   "query": {                                                                                       
    "fuzzy_like_this_field" : {                                                                     
        "firstName" : {                                                                                  
            "like_text" : "George",                                                               
            "max_query_terms" : 12                                                                  
        }                                                                                           
    }                                                                                               
   },                                                                                               
   "aggs": {                                                                                        
      "distinct_lastNames": {                                                                       
         "terms": {                                                                                 
            "field": "lastName"                                                                     
         }                                                                                          
      }                                                                                             
   }                                                                                                
}'
```

It worked for me with default `analyzer` in elasticsearch field `firstName`.

**Es Response**

```
  "aggregations": {
      "distinct_lastNames": {
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "Upd",
               "doc_count": 1
            }, 
            {
               "key": "Bale",
               "doc_count": 2
            }
         ]
      }
   }
```

**References,**

https://github.com/prayagupd/gccount/blob/master/gccount-analytics/scripts/search_customer_like.sh#L21

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-flt-field-query.html

Comment: Still not working. I got all documents when i run your query.

Comment: @placplacboom Can you post your mapping and result of query in question or somewhere?

Comment: Now it's working. I was using a different value, my mistake. Thank you for the help.